# How to get available countries and Currencies?

Tags: android, locale, currency

I try to get a list of all available countries and currencies at the same time.
I want the country names to be on spinner and when user chooses the country it's return the currency symbol.
My method works but i think it's very bad practice because it's take like 3-2 sec to load the data.
I did it like this:

```
  public ArrayList<CurrencyModel> getCountriesAndCurrency(){
        ArrayList<CurrencyModel> result = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Locale> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
        for (int i = 0; i <list.size(); i++) {
            String country = list.get(i).getDisplayCountry();
            try {
                Locale pickedLocal = new Locale(list.get(i).getISO3Language(), list.get(i).getCountry());
                String code = Currency.getInstance(pickedLocal).getCurrencyCode();
                Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(code);
                String currencySymbol = currency.getSymbol(pickedLocal);
                if(currencySymbol.length()>1){
                    currencySymbol = currency.getSymbol();
                }
                result.add(new CurrencyModel(list.get(i), country, currencySymbol));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(result, new CustomComparator());
        ArrayList<CurrencyModel> finalRes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            try {
                if(!result.get(i).getCountryName().equals(result.get((i+1)).getCountryName())) {
                    finalRes.add(result.get(i));
                }
            }catch (Exception e){}
        }
        Collections.sort(finalRes, new CustomComparator());
        return finalRes;
    }

    public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<CurrencyModel> {
        @Override
        public int compare(CurrencyModel o1, CurrencyModel o2) {
            return o1.getCountryName().compareTo(o2.getCountryName());
        }
    }
```

CurrencyModel object is = locale locale ,String countryName , String currencySymbol.

there is better solution for this action?

Comment: You can save/cache it to sharedPreferences when you get it at first, if it takes too much time.

Comment: i have updated the answer with more enhancements (supposed) please check and post the results back, if you had any enhancements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found couple of things could help you
not sure though if they will significantly enhance the result

1- Locale re-instantiate
`Locale pickedLocal = new Locale(list.get(i).getISO3Language(), list.get(i).getCountry());`
why you recreate the locale , using a `locale` attributes?
you just have to assign it:

```
Locale pickedLocal = list.get(i);
```

2- same for Currency,

```
String code = Currency.getInstance(pickedLocal).getCurrencyCode();
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(code);
String currencySymbol = currency.getSymbol(pickedLocal);
```

as i understand, your target is getting `currencySymbol`, so just do it like this:

```
String currencySymbol = Currency.getInstance(pickedLocal).getSymbol();
```

so the final block of code (the one with try-catch) should look like this

```
try {
    Locale pickedLocal = list.get(i);
    String currencySymbol = Currency.getInstance(pickedLocal).getSymbol();
    if(currencySymbol.length()>1){
        currencySymbol = currency.getSymbol();
    }
    result.add(new CurrencyModel(pickedLocal, country, currencySymbol));
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

at `result.add(new CurrencyModel(list.get(i),...` use pickedLocal, don't re-get item from the list.

that's what i got so far, i will append any further finds to this answer.

**EDIT: (maybe you will have to sort the mail "list" first)**
a second look into the code, i found that you try to remove duplicates after you populate results list, if you check the result list before adding new item, you will get rid of the second loop

```
try {
    Locale pickedLocal = list.get(i);
    String currencySymbol = Currency.getInstance(pickedLocal).getSymbol();
    if(currencySymbol.length()>1){
        currencySymbol = currency.getSymbol();
    }

    //TO AVOID the second loop (check duplicates), add only if not exist
    final int size = result.size();
    if(size > 0){
        if(!result.get(size-1).getCountryName().equals(country)){
            //no similar item was added yet, so add the new item
            result.add(new CurrencyModel(pickedLocal, country, currencySymbol));
        }
    }else{
        //it still empty, just add the new item
        result.add(new CurrencyModel(pickedLocal, country, currencySymbol));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks anyway .. but i just using with asyncTask and it works much faster